# Filter by projected field in CAML - is it possible?

Tags: caml-query

I have a `Dealers` list with the following structure:

```
ID | Title | DealerCode
```

and `DealerLetters` list with lookup column (referencing to the `Title` field):

```
ID | Title | RegistrationNumber | RegistrationDate | Dealer
```

I need to query the `DealerLetters` list by registration number, registration date and dealer code (not ID).

I tried the following query (via CAML builder):

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
      <And>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name='RegistrationNumber' />
          <Value Type='Text'>000004</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name='RegistrationDate' />
          <Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>2013-04-16T12:31:04Z</Value>
        </Eq>
      </And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='DCode' List='dealersList' />
        <Value Type='Text'>000004</Value>
      </Eq>
    </And>
  </Where>
  <Joins>
    <Join Type='INNER' ListAlias='dealersList'>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Dealer' RefType='Id' />
        <FieldRef List='dealersList' Name='ID' />
      </Eq>
    </Join>
  </Joins>
  <ProjectedFields>
    <Field Name='DCode' Type='Lookup' List='dealersList' ShowField='DealerCode' />
  </ProjectedFields>
</Query>
```

I'm getting this when running the query:

```
One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these field.
```

Is it possible to include projected fields in `Where` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539975%28v=office.14%29.aspx), your current CAML query is wrong.
In order to be able to query on a projected field, you need to make the field available by adding a reference to it to the `<ViewFields>` element (which I don't see in your code).

So, I think it's enough to add the following to your CAML:

```
<ViewFields>
  <FieldRef Name='DCode'/>
</ViewFields>
```

Also, there is no need to specify the list attribute on the where clause.

```
<Eq>
  <FieldRef Name='DCode' />
  <Value Type='Text'>000004</Value>
</Eq>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the following to help with my CAML, very handy.

[Welcome to the SharePoint CAML Generator](http://www.camlgenerator.com/)

> The CAML Generator is a Durandal SPA web application.  It generates
>   code that you can use to query SharePoint via: jQuery, Javascript
>   Client Object Model, SharePoint Server Object Model, and SharePoint
>   Client Object Model.

It works with both "connected" and "disconnected" situations.

Answer (score 0):

Test The CAML Generator is a Durandal SPA web application. It generates code that you can use to query SharePoint via: jQuery, Javascript Client Object Model, SharePoint Server Object Model, and SharePoint Client Object Model.The CAML Generator is a Durandal SPA web application. It generates code that you can use to query SharePoint via: jQuery, Javascript Client Object Model, SharePoint Server Object Model, and SharePoint Client Object Model.